# Electrical problem in my home

Tags: electrical, walls

I have a circuit on a 20 amp single pole breaker. All it has on it is two lighted ceiling fans on 1 single switch; it operates both ceiling fan lights and fan. It has a receptacle as well. My panel is around 35-37 years old. That is all that is on that circuit. What could be possibly wrong with the circuit? I checked Voltage on everything. It reads 120v very good. It might stay good for 2-5 days then loose power on everything on that circuit.

Comment: Does the breaker trip when the circuit loses power? Is there a TEST button on the breaker?  Can you post photos of the breaker panel, including the label on the inside of the door?

Comment: No the breaker does not trip at all. There is no test button or GFCI on the circuit at all. Just what is listed above. Voltage reads good on all; hot to neutral, & , hot to ground. I could have sworn the other day when I flipped the 20 amp breaker for that circuit; killed power to it the power did not go out. The circuit and all on it was still hot.

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel?

Comment: It has been painted over. Breakers are Eaton. I will send photo.

Comment: How does the power get restored after it goes out?

Comment: I just wait a little while and it will come back on. It’s on a Cutler Hammer CHF120 20 Amp Breaker.

Comment: Since you measure power I would guess you have a loose neutral someplace it could be in the switch box or at the fan. I have had customers say no the neutral is good I am reading 110v.  I high impedance meter may even show 120v with the neutral totally disconnected. About a week ago we had some lights go out in our barn, I was reading 120v at the fixture unloaded but when I tried with the light plugged in it was down to 4v, my son said he could hear some buzzing , he had accidentally cut the cable neutral when hanging some bikes in the rafters. Since it is intermittent I would verify wire nuts

Comment: Check if the bachstabs were used in wiring the switch

Comment: Ok Ed Beal. Yes Jack who ever wired it used the backstabs to terminate it. I will definitely check all neutrals as well

Comment: Get rid of the backstabs and use the screw terminals: neutral, white, to sliver and black, hot, to brass.  Backstabs are notorious for causing problems like you've got.

Comment: Ok will do. I will let you know the outcome. I appreciate all the help

Comment: Fixed it. It was the stabs and a loose neutral

Comment: Now to my next question. Wiring a out door shed that has everything that a home does; bathroom kitchen living room and extra bedroom. Pretty much like a guest home you can say. When I run my wire in the bathroom of it. The GFCI Receptacle does it have to be on a separate circuit than the lights in the bathroom ? Does every receptacle in the bathroom have to be GFCI?